# Execute a php file through a terminal that can login and retrieve information

Tags: php, curl

The idea is that I need to execute a php file through a linux terminal, when I execute it, it has to login to a website and retrieve the information of that website, I am going to give example codes.

This is index.php

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="value1"/>
    <input type="text" name="value2"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

This is the file i have to execute : phpLoad.php

```
$url = "http://localhost/Spider/index.php";  
$postdata = "value1=1234&value2=ohyeah";
$handler = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POST,true);  
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);  
$response = curl_exec ($handler);  
curl_close($handler); 

echo $response;
```

Now if I execute this from a console

php phpLoad.php I get
The echo I receive is  the following:

```
dan@dan-VirtualBox:/var/www/html/Spider$ php cargaDatos.php 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="value1"/>
    <input type="text" name="value2"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>

<p>Hola</p>

</body>
</html>1
```

the number 1 is the echo of the $response,this means its was a success...but that's it, I am not going into the action="test.php" in the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I well understood what you want, you should either

- Send a POST request as you actually do, but to **test.php** and not to index.php. Note that can work only if there is no [CSRF token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) on the form on index.php
- Use a Web client (as Symfony framework does during functional tests) like [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) to load index.php, fill form's fields and submit the form.

Comment: It worked, I used your first option "Send a POST request as you actually do, but to test.php and not to index.php. Note that can work only if there is no CSRF token on the form on index.php" in test.php I have `code` echo "I am logued in"; `code` if I am logged in, I just gave a example of my real problem, but with this solved I can continue. Thanks

Comment: you can easily grab a CSRF token with curl, and post it with curl later. i usually parse out the token with DOMDocument~

Comment: @hanshenrik It is possible to send a CSRF token, but to send the right token it is necessary to view the form first. It dreid does a request directly to the submit page he can't know the token.

Comment: CSRF do you mean the forms attribute? just right click and view source code and you can get it, in any case It worked with the example code, you told me to send a POST request to test.php but in a real website how can i know who is handling the valiidations?

Comment: In a real website that has a CSRF token, you could use Goutte as I said in the answer to really use the form like any real user, or you can do a request with *curl* to the form page (index), parse HTML to get the token and then do an other request to validation page (test.php).
Of course the easier way is to use a client, like Goutte or other to use the website as any user could do.

Comment: I can't use Goutte here, how do I know If the login was a success?

Comment: The server sould tell you your login and/or password are wrong. It can redirect you onto index.php for instante, or try to access to a page that requires an authenticate user. If you are not logged in you'll can not access to this page.